# Get character with most occurences in a string

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

I've been trying to wrap my head around this for some time now, but haven't been able to come up with an elegant solution.

The problem: I have a string with different characters ("ABDDEEDDC") and I need to know which character occurs the most. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Cheers, Niko

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know of any built in support for it, but you can use the `charAt()` property of strings, and associative arrays to do the following:

```
var charCounter:Object = new Object();
var str:String = "ABDDEEDDC";
var maxCount:int = 0;
var maxChar:String = "";

for(var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
    // Must make sure the associate array is initialised!
    if(charCounter.hasOwnProperty(str.charAt(i)) {
        charCounter[str.charAt(i)]++;
    } else {
        charCounter[str.charAt(i)] = 1;
    }
    if(charCounter[str.charAt(i)] > maxCount) {
        maxCount = charCounter[str.charAt(i)];
        maxChar = str.charAt(i);
    }
}
```

At the end of this the character should be in maxChar, and the number of times it appears in maxCount.

[`charAt()`](http://www.adobe.com/livedocs/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/String.html#charAt%28%29).

[Associative Arrays](http://www.adobe.com/livedocs/flash/9.0/main/wwhelp/wwhimpl/common/html/wwhelp.htm?context=LiveDocs_Parts&file=00000090.html).

(Sidenote: I believe that instead of `charCounter.hasOwnProperty(str.charAt(i))` you can use `str.charAt(i) in charCounter`, but I've not tested it.)

Comment: Thanks for your reply! For some reason I can't get any output using your code, can't seem to find the problem either, what could be wrong?

Comment: You forgot to initialize them. Change `charCounter[str.charAt(i)] += 1;` to `if(charCounter.hasOwnProperty([str.charAt(i)])) charCounter[str.charAt(i)] ++;else charCounter[str.charAt(i)] = 1;` @nikoka

Comment: +1 for providing an example and adding more details to my "answer approach"

Comment: Ah, I knew I'd forgotten something. Sorry nikoka, I had forgotten to initialise the values in the map. Cheers @Amarghosh! I will update my answer.

Answer (score 0):

There is as far as I know no built-in support for this. 
But you can iterate through the string with `String.charAt()` and maybe save the results in an array. 
If the array already contains the specific char you can increase a number or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

or you could split it into an array, sort and then just count up each value

```
var str:String = "ABDDEEDDC";
var a:Array = str.split('');
a.sort();
var currChar:String = '';
var currCount:int = 0;
var maxChar:String = '';
var maxCount:int = 0;
for(var i:int=0; a[i]; i++){
    if(currChar == a[i]) {
        currCount++;
        if(currCount > maxCount){
            maxCount = currCount;
            maxChar = currChar;
        }
    } else {
        currChar = a[i];
        currCount = 1;
    }
}
trace(maxChar + ' occurs '+maxCount+' times');
```